# Open my app with a URL, Then Load the link

Tags: ios, objective-c, url

I have a web browser app with a URL Identifier/Scheme "wb".

ok, when the user typing wb:// in safari, my app will open. Perfect!

but, if the user typing "wb://www.facebook.com" in safari, I want to open "facebook.com" in my app.

How do i get the link after the "wb://" ?

I'm using (This:) in my AppDelegate.m :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
    // Display text
    UIAlertView *alertView;
    NSString *text = [[url host] stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Text:" message:text delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
    return YES;
}
```

and get the link when the users types the link.

but how did I get it to my ViewController.m so i can load my webview with the text.

Comment: Basically you register a scheme in your plist. When someone triggers that URL, your app is called and you can handle the request in handleOpenURL.

Answer (score -1):

You could provide an implementation for `application:handleOpenUrl:` in your AppDelegate like:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url 
{
  // Do whatever is needed with the provided url
}
```

Comment: `application:handleOpenURL:` is deprecated, use `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:` instead.

Comment: Yes, but how did i get the "url" to my "ViewController.m" ?